# Is the entire set $M$ on which a topology is defined,, $(M,\mathscr O)$ a neighborhood of any point $x\in M$?

Tags: general-topology

If we define topology $\mathscr O$ on a set $X$, such that for every point $x \in X$, there is a neighborhood containing $x$ and a surrounding open set, I think that one of the conditions of the construct is that if a neighborhood, $N(x)$ of the point $x$ is such that $N(x)\subseteq M$, then $M$ is also a neighborhood of the point $x$.

If this is true, it would seem as though the entire set $X$ could be considered a neighborhood of $x$. And if so, wouldn't it be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and in fact one of the conditions of the definition of a topology is that both $\emptyset$ and $X$ be open - in particular, this means that the whole space $X$ (and $\emptyset$) are both open and closed. (Remember that closed sets aren't defined separately, but rather *in terms of* open sets: a set is closed iff its complement is open.)

Comment: Is there any "visual" you have in mind when writing your answer? Some sort of the neighborhoods getting larger and larger until they are the entire torus?

Comment: Not really, I'm just using the usual definition of a topology: see the "open set definition" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Definition). The "neighborhoods definition" more directly relates to your question, but is less commonly used, so I would focus on the one in terms of open sets.

Comment: Right. I think that's what through me off - I was used to the topology being defined as a subset of open sets, including the empty set and the entire original set, as well as any unions, and finite intersections. The neighborhood definition is possibly an alternative way of looking at the same concept (?).